# R and Gviz: How to remove (/crop) a region of a plot?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, r-grid

This code:

```
alTrack <- Gviz::AlignmentsTrack(
  system.file(package = "Gviz", "extdata", "gapped.bam"),
  isPaired = TRUE)

Gviz::plotTracks(
  alTrack,
  from = 3048500,
  to = 3049000,
  chromosome = "chr12")
```

Produces this plot:

[image]

Using the [Gviz](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Gviz.html) package. My problem is the empty space that's always appearing in the bottom of the picture. **How can I remove a specific region of this plot / crop to only keep the region I need?** If I could remove the lower 15% of a produced plot with an R function that would be great.

The specific region I want to not appear:

[image]

Comment: I've not used this package myself, but in the few examples I found on the web this margin doesn't appear. Since there is no range given when calling `Gviz::AlignmentsTrack`, is it possible that `alTrack` contains "extra" tracks that simply have nothing to plot within the stated range? I.e., could these be filtered within the desired range prior to plotting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max.height parameter will do it.

Already answered here:
https://support.bioconductor.org/p/81044/

Comment: Thank you! I had forgotten to link to that from here :)